# Navigation to same page in JSF1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am having a h:commandButton button named cancel on a JSF1.2 page, when a user press this button he should be redirected to the same page. How it can be achieved in JSF1.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remember to set `immediate="true"` attribute, by default, the  tag will invoke all the validators etc.., before invoking the application.

Your button:

```
<h:commandButton value="cancel" action="cancel"  title="Cancel this page" />
```

Your faces-context.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>cancel</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: no commandButton was not in h:form tag so it was not working. after putting commandButton in h:from it's working now thanks v much.